# Why are probability distributions called «lois» in French?

Tags: mathématiques, droit-et-justice, jeux

See, for example «[Loi normale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_normale),» the French version of “[Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)” on Wikipedia.

> “The cards are dealt.” «Les cartes sont **distribuées**.»

I realize that's “the way it is” in all extant academic mathematical literature in the French language, but the idiom of playing cards being laid down on the table as “law” -- in any way, shape, or form or manner of speaking -- is so offensive to me as to completely rule out any polite discourse on the subject.

«Une distribution» is a perfectly valid and decent French word.

«La distribution normale» would be a fine way to describe in French what is called “the normal distribution” in English. The mathematical language of the dealing of a deck of cards ought not to be conflated with that of legislation, civil suits, or crime and punishment under any circumstances.

Comment: As a scientist with experience in Russian, English and French, I would say that the use of such terms is idiosyncratic. E.g., the use of *power* in exponent doesn't make any sense to me, just like Russian *degree* is nonsensical in English in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that "scientific law" has a precise definition, which isn't related to law : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law

I agree with you that it's surprising to use the term in mathematics/statistics, but it seems to be used in several occasions, such as the "law of large numbers". I think this is acceptable in the sense of scientific law, i.e. which was discovered through experimentation.

And this definition of "scientific law" is a different concept than the "legal law".

Comment: The "law" in English or any Germanic or Romance language being essentially by definition "that which is laid down" -- even if it is mathematically in sense of vice as a dealer laying down cards on the table.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing specific with this usage in French. For example, *demand and offer law* or *law of thermodynamics* have no relationship with crime and punishment either.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/law):

> 6 a: a statement of an order or relation of phenomena that so far as is known is invariable under the given conditions
>   // a law of thermodynamics
>   // Boyle's law
> b: a general relation proved or assumed to hold between mathematical or logical expressions

Same in Spanish:

[RAE](https://dle.rae.es/ley)

> 2. f. Cada una de las relaciones existentes entre los diversos elementos que intervienen en un fenómeno.